# Need help finding a sum

Tags: summation, multinomial-theorem

I found this problem that I'm not sure how to solve. I would appreciate if anyone could point me to the right direction.

I need to find the following sum:

$\sum_{i+j+k=7} (-1)^i(-1)^j\frac{7!}{i!j!k!}$ where $i,j,k$ are elements of $\mathbb{N_0}$

There must be a much better way to solve this other than writing down all possible combinations and sum them (please correct me if I'm wrong).

The thing I believed could be useful was the multinomial theorem (I apologize if this is not the correct term in English), which states that:

$(\sum_{i=1}^k x_i)^n=\sum_{\sum_{i=1}^k n_i =n}\frac{n!}{\prod_{i=1}^k n_i!}\prod_{i=1}^k x_i^{n_i}$

But I'm missing $(-1)^k$.

I'm a bit new to this subject, but couldn't find any example like this in my books. Thank you in advance!

EDIT: My apologies to anyone who read the original question, I've misplaced $i$ and $j$, didn't see it while revising what I wrote. It's fixed now.

Comment: Try to expand $(1-1-1)^7$, see what you will get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no $(-1)^k$ because $x_3$ is going to be $1$: $$-1=((-1)+(-1)+1)^7=\sum_{i+j+k=7} (-1)^i(-1)^j(1)^k\frac{7!}{i!j!k!}$$

Comment: That's elegant (+1).

Comment: Makes perfect sense now. Can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

Set $k=3,\,n=7,\,x_1=1,\,x_2=x_3=-1$ so your sum becomes $(-1)^{7}=-1$.

Comment: How can you fix $k$?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I counted how many numbers were summed in $i+j+k=7$.

Comment: (+1) I see there are two colliding $k$s in the OP.